# More efficient way to apply alternating row style to GridView in TabContainers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, ajax

I am working on a page that use the Ajax Control Toolkit's `TabContainer`. In each `TabPanel` there is a GridView.

```
<act:TabContainer runat="server">
    <act:TabPanel runat="server">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ...>
        </asp:GridView>
    </act:TabPanel>
      ...
    <act:TabPanel runat="server">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ...>
        </asp:GridView>
    </act:TabPanel>
</act:TabContainer>
```

Then on the front-end, a JQuery tablesorter is bound to the tables. After the tablesorter is bound, the rows are styled in an alternating fashion, this is done with the following bit of code:

```
var rows = $('tr.Clickable');

for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i += 2) {
    var oddrow = 'tr.Clickable:eq(' + i.toString() + ');';
    $(oddrow).addClass('odd');
}
```

On some machines, the browser returns a warning that a script is taking too long to finish, and this happened right after the previous javascript was added. I think that the use of the selector: `tr.Clickable:eq(n)` is the culprit.

I would like to just loop over the `rows` array and do an `.addClass('odd')` for rows with and index that is odd, however, the elements of the `rows` array don't have an `.addClass` method, so I used the `:eq` selector to compensate.

This works, but very slowly, is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector

```
$('tr.Clickable:odd').addClass('odd');
```